# some error/warning messages for running Tensorflow implementation

Tags: tensorflow

When running a Tensorflow implementation, I got the following error/warning messages, which does not include the line of python code that causes this issue. At the same time, the result is still generated. I am not sure what do these messages indicate?

```
 Exception ignored in: <bound method Session.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x2b48ec89f748>>
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/data/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-    packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 140, in __del__
 File "/data/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 137, in close
 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'status' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: This is still an open bug in tensorflow - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3388

Answer (score 1):

Today I also encountered this exception while running some Multi layer perceptron model on Windows 10 64 Bit with Python 3.5 and TensorFlow 0.12

I have seen this answer for this  exception

> it induced by different gc sequence, if python collect session first , the program will exit successfully, if python collect swig memory(tf_session) first, the program exit with failure.
>   [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3388)